# How to click dropdown-toggle ng-binding selenium click element in java

Tags: java, selenium

I can not find a way to click on the following menu item:

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBMq2.png)

Tests were carried out with:

```
js.executeScript("$('html > body > div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > div:eq(0) > ul > li:eq(0) > ul > li:eq(1) > a').click();");
```

And

```
driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle")).click();
```

Your help please.

Comment: it works: List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-toggle .ng-binding"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-toggle .ng-binding"));
elements.get(1).click();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are not too much IDs, so you need to use some unique locator, I suggest to use that one:

```
  WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='cssmenu']/.//a[@ng-click='setProject(opcion.url)']"));
  link.click;
```

Comment: Ok, could you please provide HTML block as text?

Comment: `<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle ng-binding" ng-click="setProject(opcion.url)" xpath="1">
                                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i> <i class="menu-icon icon-caret-right"></i> Mis Declaraciones DAM
                            </a>` Thanks.